# Not Able to Get Height of Position Relative Element Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to have a position relative div plus some some position absolute contents inside it. Now I am trying to dynamically calculate the height of the `#one` and then apply it to top of `#two` at this demo

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/gevjrfqc/1/)

but I am getting `20` (it seems it is not calculating the height of the image inside the `#one`! can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var contentheight = $('#one').height();
    console.log(contentheight);
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
       var contentheight = $('#one').height();
       $("#two").css("top", bodyheight);
   });
 });
```

Comment: why the code insert not working!

Comment: You've positioned the image absolutely, which means it is taken out of the document flow and will not contribute to the height of its wrapping parent.

Comment: Thanks Terry but what is the solution then?

Comment: If you set the image position to relative, does that give you the layout you're after?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you're trying to do exactly. Maybe the use of JS is not even needed.

Comment: I am trying to write some text over an image and in continue add some new stuff into the page